# How can I extract comments and function names from C++ or C or Java with perl

Tags: perl

I'm dealing with an assignment, and I'm really new to Perl. Don't understand it really well.
Could you guys guid me to extract the comments and the function names of these three kind of files (C, C++ and Java)?

I have already tried this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use File::Find;
use File::Slurp;
use Regexp::Common qw /comment/;
    my $fileName = "a.java";
    my $wordsIn = "";
    my $wordsIdentifier="";
    my $numRemoved = 0;

    #$wordsOut = `xscc.awk extract=comment prune=copyright $fileName`;
    $wordsIn = read_file($fileName) ;
    # Find all matches of comments, and put them into @arr
    my @arr = $wordsIn =~  m/$RE{comment}{Java}/g;
    my $wordsOut = join(" ", @arr);
    print "Comments:\n";
    print $wordsOut;
    $wordsIn =~ s/$RE{comment}{Java}//g;
    print "Identifiers:\n";
    print $wordsIn;
```

It perfectly gets the comments(even I don't know how!), but for retrieving the identifiers and methods names what should I do for the $RE{comment}{Java}

Regards 
Ehsan

Comment: Did you try something? Share it with us

Comment: What is the purpose of what you're doing?  Is it just an exercise, or are you solving a problem with this information?  If you let us know the ultimate goal, we might find an easier way to do it.

Comment: It is an exercise, but since I'm a grad student so it would be somehow solving a problem for a survey:)

Answer (score 2):

Regexp::Common doesn't provide a regex for it, so you'd have to do it on your own. This is very complicated due to the number of possible formats. In C, for example, you'd want to search for:

```
<type> <identifier - save this> (<comma-separated list of types and identifiers>)
{
```

But you don't necessarily know every possible type (typedefs in include files), and between optional whitespace and comments, not to mention old-style function definitions, it may be difficult to catch every case.

As it turns out, writing a lexer for C is actually pretty tough, and it's even harder when you don't know things like typedefs that may be many include files deep and when you don't implement the entire preprocessor. The common example, not applicable in your case, is `(A)*B`, which you can't tell if it's a multiplication or a typecast of a scalar dereference without checking all the includes for typedefs.

Answer (score 2):

There's two basic approaches: use a pre-existing parser or use a compiler to give you the information you need.

For C, there is [C::Scan](https://metacpan.org/module/C%3a%3aScan) to get function declarations (and much more) out from C (and a lot of C++).  Or you might be able to get [gcc](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html) to give you the information you want.

As for Java, that's harder.  One possibility is to figure out how [Inline::Java](https://metacpan.org/module/Inline%3a%3aJava) does it.  Alternatively, you could try using [the parser from Eclipse](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ast/).

A possibility for mining existing "good enough" regexes is from [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) or other editors which do syntax highlighting.  I mention TextMate because I find its language parsing to be the easiest to understand.  You can probably mine their Java bundle for the necessary regexes.

If this is just a regex exercise, then the lesson is this sort of thing is too complicated for a regex.  For languages you need a grammar and a parser for that grammar.